# Column vs Table Primary Key constraint in a SQLite table

Tags: sqlite, primary-key

I'm medling with SQLite databases, and from the [documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_createtable.html) :

> Each table in SQLite may have at most one PRIMARY KEY. If the keywords
>   PRIMARY KEY are added to a column definition, then the primary key for
>   the table consists of that single column. Or, if a PRIMARY KEY clause
>   is specified as a table-constraint, then the primary key of the table
>   consists of the list of columns specified as part of the PRIMARY KEY
>   clause.

My question is when there's a single column to be used as a `PRIMARY KEY`, is there a fundamental difference between the two following commands ?

```
CREATE TABLE t (x INTEGER, y TEXT ,  PRIMARY KEY (x));

CREATE TABLE t (x INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, y TEXT);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is not a difference (apart from naming the Text column once y and once t).
But as already said in the quote, there can be a difference. If you need two or more columns to be the primary key you must use the first command.
By personal preference I always use the first version because I think it is easier to read.